# Installing gmpy with an Anaconda distribution of Python 2 (Windows)

Tags: python, anaconda, gmpy

I am trying to use a program called [CatMAP](http://catmap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) that makes heavy use of the gmpy dependency (I think it's gmpy, not gmpy2 based on the installation instructions).

I have Python 2.7.12 via Anaconda but am having a lot of trouble installing gmpy. Doing `pip install gmpy` doesn't work, and all the versions I've found on Anaconda Cloud are for Linux. Any suggestions?

The error message from the `pip install` method is shown below:

```
Collecting gmpy
  Using cached gmpy-1.17.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: gmpy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for gmpy ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\envs\python2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\andre\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-wu9jm7\\gmpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d c:\users\andre\appdata\local\temp\tmphhh_2jpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'gmpy' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src
  C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\envs\python2\include -IC:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\envs\python2\PC /Tcsrc/gmpy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/gmpy.obj
  gmpy.c
  c:\users\andre\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-wu9jm7\gmpy\src\gmpy.h(30) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gmp.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for gmpy
  Running setup.py clean for gmpy
Failed to build gmpy
Installing collected packages: gmpy
  Running setup.py install for gmpy ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\envs\python2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\andre\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-wu9jm7\\gmpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\andre\appdata\local\temp\pip-uvzbnt-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'gmpy' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src
    C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\envs\python2\include -IC:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\envs\python2\PC /Tcsrc/gmpy.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src/gmpy.obj
    gmpy.c
    c:\users\andre\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-wu9jm7\gmpy\src\gmpy.h(30) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gmp.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\andre\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Users\andre\Anaconda3\envs\python2\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\andre\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-wu9jm7\\gmpy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\andre\appdata\local\temp\pip-uvzbnt-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\andre\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-wu9jm7\gmpy\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `CatMAP` uses `mpmath` there is a good chance `gmpy` is only needed to improve the performance of `mpmath`. Assuming that is true, `gmpy2` will work since `mpmath` supports either `gmpy` or `gmpy2`.

You can find pip compatible wheels for `gmpy` and `gmpy2` [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)